# Can SQL Server Connection String Contain Options like XACT_ABORT?

Tags: .net, connection-string, sql-server-2012

Can SQL string contain options like `XACT_ABORT`. For example, I can execute set `XACT_ABORT On`, but I would like to set this option in connection string. Is it possible? I tried to write `XACT_ABORT=On;` and `XACT_ABORT=yes;`, but that didnt work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not possible. The possible options are documented here:

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130822.aspx
2. http://www.connectionstrings.com/all-sql-server-connection-string-keywords

I also advise you to stick to the default options because that is what everyone uses. The product works best one you are close to the defaults. Also, help on the web will be easier to obtain.